# SQL Server UPDATE column value from another table's column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I have two tables:

**T1**:

```
CODE  FULL_NAME
```

and **T2**:

```
CODE   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME
```

all of the columns are of type `NVARCHAR`.

Some `CODE` cells in `T1` are empty and I need to get them from `T2`. I need to use `FULL_NAME` information in `T1` and search in `LAST_NAME` and `FIRST_NAME` columns in `T2`. How to write such an `UPDATE`?

What I wrote so far is:

```
UPDATE IMPORT_DATA.RDBS_DATA_STORAGE
SET child_iin = pd.iin
FROM IMPORT_DATA.RDBS_DATA_STORAGE
INNER JOIN nedb.PERSONAL_DATA pd ON child_iin LIKE 'N' + '%' + pd.LAST_NAME + '%' + ' ' + 'N' + '%' + 
pd.FIRST_NAME + '%'
```

WHERE LEN(child_iin) < 1;

But unsuccessful.

**EDIT:**

I can't just use `WHERE t1.FULL_NAME=t2.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + t2.LAST_NAME`, because i can have such scenario where `t1.FULL_NAME` = `'Jorsh Arthur Weasley'` and `t1.FIRST_NAME`=`'William'`, `t2.LAST_NAME`=`'Weasley'`.

Also.

I need to use `N`, because as i said the columns are type of `NVARCHAR` and i have non-ASCII letters there, so for example:

`SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE CODE = 'Неважно'` retruns nothing, to fix this i have to add `N`: `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE CODE = N'Неважно'` returns a row.

Comment: *"But unsuccessful."* What does this mean? Did you get an error, it didn't work as expected, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Larnu please, take a look at edit

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.CODE = T2.Code 
From T1
Join T2 on t1.FULL_NAME= t2.FIRST_NAME + ' ' +t2.LAST_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simple need :

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.code = t2.code
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.FULL_NAME = t2.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + t2.LAST_NAME
WHERE t1.code IS NULL;
```

Comment: i can't use `t1.FULL_NAME = t2.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + t2.LAST_NAME` i need to use `LIKE` because i can have such scenario: `FULL_NAME`: `Jorsh William Weasley` and `FIRST_NAME`:`Jorsh`, `LAST_NAME`: `Weasley`. Can you please update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
UPDATE IMPORT_DATA.RDBS_DATA_STORAGE
SET child_iin = pd.iin
FROM IMPORT_DATA.RDBS_DATA_STORAGE
       INNER JOIN nedb.PERSONAL_DATA pd
         ON child_iin LIKE '%' + pd.LAST_NAME + '%' + ' ' + '%' + pd.FIRST_NAME + '%'
WHERE LEN(child_iin) < 1;
```

`N`'s were unnecessary